# Third party iPhone development tools

Tags: iphone, macos, production

I'm interested, what are the tools for good practice iPhone software development (and other apple devices), except XCode & Interface Builder.

I'm talking about tools for making application prototypes, icons, classes diagrams, images, etc.

This question came up after a time of strugling with Gimp for image edition, and Axure for prototype making. I'm sure, these are not the best tools for my aims. I'm thinking of bying photoshop, or may be it's better to use some cheaper and usefull application for icons and prototypes specially.

Although, it would be good to know, if there are some convenient tools for some other purposes that i didn't mention above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm using [Acorn](http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/) for image editing

Answer (score 1):

OmniGraffle is great for rapid prototyping.

I have also used Bluprint for iPad and it is also quite nice